# Button stay "pressed" if mouseclick event is attached

Tags: java, swing

I built a Swing GUI application, and everything works quite well, except for a little detail: I have two bottons, and each of them has a mouseclick event attached. The problem is, when i click them, they stay "pressed" : everything else works fine, but it's just odd seeing those two buttons ... maybe i used the wrong event? or i should set them to "depressed" manually ?

Comment: A short but complete example would really help here.

Comment: What actions are you performing when the button is pressed down?

Comment: It would also help to know what OS and Look and Feel you are using (if not the default L&F)

Comment: You shouldn't add MouseListeners to JButtons, but instead should use ActionListeners or Action objects.

Comment: *Make sure to propagate the event* (call the default event handlers). The "stays depressed" is because an event is being swallowed and not propagated as it should be. But best is just to use an `ActionListener`, if possible.

Comment: Is you listener perhaps throwing an exception? (Whether this prevents the event getting to the correct other listener depends upon unspecified ordering.)

Comment: there's gotta be an exception getting thrown that prevents the EDT from completing the button refresh.  This is pretty typical.  As others have written - post a sub-set of the code that recreates the problem or we won't be able to help.

Comment: Hey, everybody - could you please post your suggestions as actual answers instead of comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "Answers from comments" C.W.-style.

You shouldn't add MouseListeners to JButtons, but instead should use ActionListeners or Action objects. This is the preferred method and is generally simpler if it covers the required behavior.

Make sure to propagate the event (call the default event handlers). The "stays depressed" is because an event is being swallowed and not propagated as it should be.

Is you listener perhaps throwing an exception? Whether this prevents the event getting to the correct other listener depends upon unspecified ordering and one event failing may cause the entire dispatch to fail.

There's gotta be an exception getting thrown that prevents the EDT from completing the button refresh. This is pretty typical.